# Failure while importing relations from CSV file

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I'm testing Neo4j 2.3.2 and I've issues while importing a file.

First, I'm giving information about data. I've people works at companies and each person has at least one job title (a few has 2 job titles). In our logic, job titles are categorized and every job title has a code but the same code may be in different category (called environment).

Currently, I've got 550,000 people, 15 environments and 30 job titles in the DB.

I've got a CSV file that links for each person his/her job title (in its environment). This file has the same number of records as people in the DB. So, I launch this Cypher query in the Web GUI:

```
using periodic commit 
load csv with headers from "file:///C:\\...\\individu.csv" as row
match (c:Contact {individuId: row.NUM_INDIVIDU}), (f:Fonction {rank: row.NUM_FONC})-[:DEPEND]->(e:Environnement {rank: row.NUM_ENV})
merge (c)-[:POSTE]->(f);
```

And I get this error:

> GC overhead limit exceeded

My data size is not very important so I don't understand why my import fails.

Could a bad modeling idea be to use relation of this kind ? Should I save these data as properties ? Is around 500 or 600 thousands POSTE relations is too much ?

**EDIT**
I think I found the problem. I've got 300,000 people has the same job title. Are 300,000 relations to one node too much ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your import statement uses an eager pipe which causes periodic commit not working as expected. So the import runs in one single transaction which requires too much memory and therefore causing GC issues.

There's a lot of information out there on the eager pipe issue, e.g. http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/